# Convert a number to its expression in words (e.g. 55 -> fifty-five)

Tags: apex, formula-field

Is there a way to convert a number to a string (Apex code, formula field ..) 
For example: 5200 > cinq milles deux cents

Comment: There is no way to do this natively. Coincidentally I wrote/editted a piece of PHP code that does exactly this, but that's in Dutch.

Comment: Salesforce does not support PHP

Comment: Number to Word convert apex [Convert-number-to-words-in-apex-salesforce](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40676675/convert-number-to-words-in-apex-salesforce)

Answer (score 3):

Number to Word conversion using Salesforce Apex:
http://salesforcewithkiran.blogspot.in/2013/05/number-to-words-in-apex.html